# Circle component not getting rendered in SVG in react.js

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to dynamically insert circles in SVG section, I have hardcoded 4 circles and they are getting rendered. But the circle in the ternary operator is not getting rendered, I have printed the values of cx and cy and it is correct.

```
<div className='canvas'>
            <svg width="700px" height="350px">
                {/* <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="150" y2="50" stroke={"black"} strokeWidth={4} /> */}
                <circle cx="690" cy="10" r="10" fill={"blue"} />
                <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill={"green"} />
                <circle cx="10" cy="340" r="10" fill={"blue"} />
                <circle cx="690" cy="340" r="10" fill={"green"} />
                {circles.length > 0  ? 
                    <div>
                        { circles.map((e,index)=>{
                            console.log("-----------",e[0],e[1]);
                            return <circle key={index} cx={e[0]} cy={e[1]}  r="10" fill={"blue"} />;
                        })}
                    </div> 
                :
                <div></div>
                }
            </svg>
        </div>
```

[image]

Do tell if more info is required

Comment: Why do you have a `div` in your `svg`?

Comment: @tkausl  are you asking about the div in the ternary operator ?

Comment: Yes. That shouldn't be there.

Comment: @tkausl I removed the div, and changes .map to .forEach (becauz .map was throwing an error), still not rendering

Comment: It won't work with `map` replaced by `forEach` given this code.

Comment: Please update the question with your new code and all relevant error messages.